# how to remove my stop words from a string column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, full-text-search, stop-words

I have a table with a string column. I want to remove the stop words. I used this query which seems Ok.

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english',colName)from tblName order by colName asc;
```

1. it does not update the column in table
2. I want to see the stop words of Postgresql and what the query found.Then in case I can replace it with my own file. I also checked this address and could not find the stop words list file. Actually, the address does not exist.

   ```
   $SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/english.stop
   ```

Comment: @GurV: thanks for edit

Comment: what is your data dir? `show data_directory`

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to change the data in the table? That is done with `UPDATE`. The English stop words are found on the database machine in the subdirectory `tsearch_data` of the *sharedir*, which can be found with `pg_config --sharedir`.

Comment: I am not sure how to use update , because this selection returns the words which are not the stopwords, so how can return those to update my column.

Comment: @Laurenz when I update the table, it makes a value of the column like this `'academi':2 'brixton':1`. which I do not want their index. I do not know how to update in a way that this index would not be there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function to do that.

You could use something like this (in this example in German):

```
SELECT array_to_string(tsvector_to_array(to_tsvector('Hallo, Bill und Susi!')), ' ');
 array_to_string
-----------------
 bill hallo susi
(1 row)
```

This removes stop words, but also stems and non-words, and it does not care about word order, so I doubt that the result will make you happy.

If that doesn't fit the bill, you can use `regexp_replace` like this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Bill and Susi, hand over or die!', '\y(and|or|if)\y', '', 'g');
       regexp_replace
-----------------------------
 Bill  Susi, hand over  die!
(1 row)
```

But that requires that you include your list of stop words in the query string. An improved version would store the stop words in a table.

Comment: Actually, I want to find out how a specific words distributed over my users. so I need to know the exact words. but there are different way of using the words, a lot of characters, abbreviation, and weird staff which I have to get rid of those. I need to split words and remove all nonsense characters and words.

Comment: unfortunately, stemming and shuffling the words is the last thing I want to do with my data. maybe I can use regex to get rid of the indexing.

Comment: although I have probelm to use this regex in a query ':\d'?

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer did not match my requirement, but I found a solution for this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Bill and Susi, hand over or die!', '[^ ]*$','');

regexp_replace
-----------------------------
Bill and Susi, hand over or 
(1 row)
```